# joining a thread: "resource deadlock avoided"

Tags: boost, pthreads, boost-asio, deadlock

I use a c++ class that encapsulates a **boost::asio::io_service**.

```
class IoService {
 public:
  static IoService& getInstance() {
    static IoService instance;
    return instance;
  }
  void start() {
    _ioServiceThread = std::thread(&IoService::run, this);
  }
  void stop() {
    _ioService.stop();
    _ioServiceThread.join();
  }
  void run() {
   _ioService.run();
  }

 private:
  IoService();
  ~IoService();
  IoService(const IoService& old) = delete;
  IoService(const IoService&& old) = delete;
  IoService& operator=(const IoService& old) = delete;
  IoService& operator=(const IoService&& old) = delete;

  boost::asio::io_service _ioService;
  std::thread _ioServiceThread;
};
```

But when I am calling the stop method, the program is crashing on the join:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Resource deadlock avoided
Aborted
```

What do you think ?

Comment: Provide MCVE, io_services doesn't have `join` method. Show the code where IoService is created and how start/stop are called. And where is the body of IoService destructor?

Comment: My bad, it was a typo. I am calling join on the std thread !

Answer (score 6):

That's the error that you get when a thread tries to join itself.

So it sounds like your problem is that you're calling the `stop()` method from a handler function that was invoked by the `io_service`.

Comment: I’m not sure to understand... when I call the _ioService.stop() method, it looks like I’m not exiting the _ioService.run(); method. Is it expected ? Maybe it is why the joining is not working…?

Comment: The problem is the thread context which is calling `IoService::stop()`.  You are calling it from a handler function, which means that it's being run by the thread that is running `io_service::run()`, which is the same thread you're trying to join.  You need to call the `::stop()` function from a different thread.

Comment: To be more clear on how I use the IoService class, I have two others classes A and B that have a private `IoService& _ioService;` and I call _ioService.stop() in A’s descructor. Is it bad ?

Comment: What matters is which thread runs it - so, which thread ends up running A's destructor?